# CodeIgniter and htaccess - Protect a specific controller and its methods via AuthType?

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an admin controller which has some methods that I want to protect.

http://blabla.com/admin/

http://blabla.com/admin/edit_coupon/

http://blabla.com/admin/edit_photo/

I don't need a full blown authentication system for this site, so I'd prefer to just utilize htaccess and AuthType for any /admin/ URLs.

My current .htaccess is a basic CI one.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|css|js|videos|code|robots\.txt|favic
on\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do I do this?

[Added]
I know how to use htaccess and htpasswd. My question is how to protect a CI controller which is not really a directory (/admin). I tried using the Location directive with no success. Here is that htaccess:

```
<Location /admin>  
 AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/blabla.com/httpdocs/.htpasswd
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Admin"
 Require valid-user
</Location>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|css|js|videos|code|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

That throws a 500 Server Error.

I believe the Location directive can't be in an htaccess file, so I also tried it inside this server's httpd.conf for this VirtualHost. Doesn't throw an error that way, but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by following the advice in this post:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/141775/

Comment: Worked great. Basically, create a physical folder, add CI index there, then password protect that. Flawless - for me anyway. Keeps users to url they requested, etc... thanks.

Answer (score -1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

You will need to create the .htpasswd file with the name-passwords and set up rule in your .htaccess file that requires a valid user for the to-be-protected location.

Comment: I know how to use htaccess and htpasswd. My question is how to protect a controller which is not really a directory. I tried using the Location directive with no success.

Comment: Can you post your code used for protection of the controller from your htaccess?

Comment: I've added it to the original post.